# Formar checkbox con respuesta json

Tags: html, json, datepicker

Amigos, necesito una orientacion a como realizar lo siguiente, tengo un datepicker donde selecciono una fecha y esa fecha se va a preguntar a json, esto me responde y me muestra los datos entregados, pero mi problema se genera en 2 partes:

1. Lo primero es que cuando pincho una fecha el datepicker siempre me queda abierto.
2. Y lo segundo, no se como armar mi checkbox.  Tengo este código:

   ```
   $.each(parsed, function (i, item) {
      $("#periodo").append('<input type="checkbox"  value="\' + item.Id + \'">' + item.Label);
   });
   ```

Y mi código HTML es

```
<div class="col-xl-12">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Seleccione Períodos</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="periodo" name="periodo" >                                      
   </div>
</div>
```

Me imagino que mi código no es la manera correcta de verlo, alguna idea como pueda solucionar mis inconvenientes?

Comment: No acabo de comprender, que tiene que ver el `checkbox ` que has indicado en la pregunta con el `datapicker`?

Comment: Es que al presionar el calendario, me trae de respuesta los checkbox, pero  sucede que cada que selecciono una fecha el calendario me queda abierto y los checkbox se me repiten constantemente y no es la idea

Comment: uso en mi calendario un daterangepicker